# PowerShell script to Move files into multiple sub-directories of 1000 files each

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where after restoring files from a corrupted RAID drive, I now have a single folder with approximately 110,000 RAW images in it taking up just about a terabyte.
Each file is named sequentially in numbers from 00000001.CR2 to 00110232.CR2.

This folder is more or less un-usable from my desktop due to the size and volume of this content.

What I need to do is move about 1,000 files at a time from this main folder into sub-folders named 001, 002, 003 etc. (Folders of only 1,000 files I can work with!)

So, in PowerShell I can iterate all childitems of a folder and move them, but is there a command I can pipe into that will take 1,000 file-names at a time and move them into a sequentially numbered folder?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
for ( $i=0 ; $i -le 110 ; $i++ )
 {
  $folder = $i.ToString('000')
  $file = $i.ToString('00000')

  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'c:\imagesfolder\' -Value $folder 
  Move-Item -Path "C:\imagesfolder\$file*.CR2" -Destination "c:\imagesfolder\$folder" 
 }
```

That doesn't iterate all the files, it just creates sequential zero-filled strings from 000-110, and 00000-00110, and then uses those to create the directories, and in a wildcard pattern for move-item.